# cmake - Creating a shared arm library which can be used in Android

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk, toolchain

I have a project which has armeabi-v7a folder and uses libssl.a and libcrypto.a libraries. Now i am able to compile the project with the source code c++ files and use that into a project.

Now i want cmake to create a shared library which i can use in any other project. I don't have much knowledge of cmake

What i have tried?

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$(NDK_PATH)/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_NDK=$(NDK_PATH) -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21 -DANDROID_STL=c++_shared -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/some_dir/
```

After running this

```
-- Check for working C compiler: $(NDK_PATH)/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang
-- Check for working C compiler: $(NDK_PATH)/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: $(NDK_PATH)/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: $(NDK_PATH)/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
You have changed variables that require your cache to be deleted.
Configure will be re-run and you may have to reset some variables.
The following variables have changed:
CMAKE_C_COMPILER= /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER= /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++

-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 9.1.0.9020039
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 9.1.0.9020039
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done

-- Configuring done                                                                                                                       
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: $(PATH)
```

Now when i try running

```
make
```

It gives me

```
Scanning dependencies of target dcsdk
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dcsdk.dir/src/main/cpp/DCSDK.cpp.o
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dcsdk.dir/src/main/cpp/Constants.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library libdcsdk.dylib
```

ld: warning: ld: warning: ignoring file openssl-armeabi-v7a/lib/libssl.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): openssl-armeabi-v7a/lib/libssl.aignoring file openssl-armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): openssl-armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OPENSSL_init_ssl", referenced from:
      initSSL() in DCSDK.cpp.o

Now i get the problem is that its compiling for x86_64 architecture but i have specified it in cmake to use ANDROID_ABI to armeabi-v7a.

if you need my CMakeLists.txt Here it is

```
# For more information about using CMake with Android Studio, read the
# documentation: https://d.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
         dcsdk

         # Sets the library as a shared library.
         SHARED

         # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
         src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp src/main/cpp/DCSDK.cpp src/main/cpp/Constants.cpp )

# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

#find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
#              log-lib
#
#              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
#              # you want CMake to locate.
#              log )

include_directories(openssl-armeabi-v7a/include/)
```

`include_directories(/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers/)`

```
# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                   dcsdk
                   # Links the target library to the log library
                   # included in the NDK.
                   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/openssl-armeabi-v7a/lib/libssl.a
                   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/openssl-armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a )
```

Comment: In your command line for `cmake`, try to replace all `$(NDK_PATH)` with `${NDK_PATH}`.

Comment: @AlexCohn i have already added the original path this was just to show that ndk path is set correctly.

Comment: Your incantation misses many important parameters, see how Android Studio invokes Cmake: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake#build-command

Comment: @AlexCohn i am not invoking it through android studio, i am running it through command line and hence getting the output. Though i have made progress, actually i had to define CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER and CMAKE_C_COMPILER and it created required .so file instead of dylib which was being created.