# How to Import a prebuilt *.so library and call it from the new project?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, .so

I'm currently working on a project which will use a prebuilt shared library. But I'm quite confused on the process of importing a prebuilt library, as well as calling the methods in the prebuilt from the new project java class.

Let's say:

1. Project A has generated the libA.so files for each ABI_ARCH.
2. I'm trying to use them in my Project B.

What is the proper way to import them, and how to call the methods of libA.so which are declared in A. In another word how to use the exposed APIs of libA.so ?

Answer (score 5):

These days Google has pre-released a [new feature](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#native-dependencies) that will allow easy reuse of prebuilt native libraries. If you are not ready yet to jump to Android Studio 4.0, and/or to build the necessary **AAR** for **libA**, you can use the old ways.

There are three different tracks, depending on what the nature of your **Project B** is.

1. If it only loads **libA.so** from Java/Kotlin, it's enough to specify `jniLibs.src` in **build.gradle**: *[How can I add .so files to an android library project using gradle 0.7+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22072984/192373)*. Note that all classes that have native methods which are implemented in **libA.so** must be copied to **Project B** keeping their *fully qualified names* intact.
2. If the second project uses **ndk-build**, you should [`include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15165763/192373). An NDK [guide](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/prebuilts) has further up-to-date details.
3. If the project uses **CMake**, you use [`add_library(… SHARED IMPORTED)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46733479/192373). An Android Srudio [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/configure-cmake#add-other-library) explains different scenarios.

It's important to emphasise a tiny difference between **ndk-build** and **CMake** in their treatment of prebuilt `.so` libraries. While **ndk-build** will copy these libraries to the installation directory with all libraries that it builds, **CMake** does not provide this *assistance*. Therefore, you will probably add the folder that holds the prebuilt library to `jniLibs.src` in **build.ghradle** (as in the case 1 above).

In all 3 scenarios, make sure that the libraries that you get packed into your APK or AAB are stripped of debug symbols.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried using the 1st approach by copying the *.so file to /main/jniLibs/ and added jnilibs.src on build.gradle, also using System.loadLibrary("A") to load the jniLib. When I tried run the app, it crash with an error said "didn't find class A"

Comment: In addition, the above error occurs when the *.so files are compiled from c++; When the *.so files are complied from .c the error was "No implementation found for long A.method(long)..."

Comment: It turns out to be the mismatch of package name, the new project has to have an identical package and class to use the *.so files.

Comment: @HangAlec: you don't need to change the package name for the whole project. Only the classes that have native methods which are implemented in **libA.so**, must be copied to **Project B** keeping their *fully qualified names* intact.