# Cmake Ninja error android. "missing and no known rule to make it" although file exists

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, ninja

I keep getting a

> ninja: error: '/root/code/CalcLib/libCalcLibAndroidx86.a', needed by
> '/root/code/compcorpsdk/build/intermediates/cmake/prod/release/obj/x86/libJumboFFT.so',
> missing and no known rule to make it

Although I checked both directories with the correct files exist and I believe I have the include-directories paths set up correctly in the CmakeList.txt.

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

set(
P1 "/root/code/CalcLib"
CACHE STRING ""
)

message(${ANDROID_ABI})

file(GLOB CPP_FILES "*.cpp")

add_library(
JumboFFT
SHARED
${CPP_FILES}
)

include_directories(src/main/jni)
include_directories(${P1})

target_link_libraries(
JumboFFT
log
android
OpenSLES
${P1}/libCalcLibAndroid${ANDROID_ABI}.a
)
```

**Gradle Assemble output**
[Gradle Asemble output text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWZWc.png)

Answer (score 5):

```
set_target_properties
```

in cmake does not like relative paths

see here:
[cmake:missing and no known rule to make it when I import a prebuilt library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41478323/cmakemissing-and-no-known-rule-to-make-it-when-i-import-a-prebuilt-library)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should add it first as a library using `add_library` and `set_target_properties` and then link it as such:

```
...

add_library(libCalcLibAndroid STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libCalcLibAndroid PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES ""
  IMPORTED_LOCATION "${P1}/libCalcLibAndroid${ANDROID_ABI}.a"
)

target_link_libraries(
JumboFFT
log
android
OpenSLES
libCalcLibAndroid
)
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply i just tried it but no luck :( same error